# Issues with the colour / clarity of my brew

Tags: color

I made my first proper brew today and was wondering about the colour. It did not have the colour I thought it would have. I used 4 cups of pale malt, one cup of Halcyon, one cup of Maris Otter and also one cup of Amber Malt.

What I ended up with had a brownish complexity that I did not entirely expect. Is this the colour / clarity these malts give or am I doing something incorrectly?

[image: my beer]

Comment: What colour you did expect?

Comment: I thought it would be more clear.

Comment: so you are not asking about color at all, only about clarity. These are independent. Please correct your question.

Comment: OK made an edit.

Comment: What Amber malt did you use? Is this pre or post fermentation? Why is your beer in a clear glass bottle by a window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as my intuition goes, the color is just as I would expect. Might be a bit more red, but within my expectations all right. You used not-so-pale pale malts, and a bit of amber, so you couldn't have brown nor yellow. And addition of floor-malted malt might have caused more brownish and less reddish tint to your wort.

For clarity, it's also not unexpected. Wort clarity depends on filtration. Post boil clarity on hot and cold break, too.

My wort was usually similarly hazy preboil. Both extract and full grain. Only recently I learnt how to filter it better. But it always settled down anyway after fermentation. How much - depends on many parameters. But wort this opaque was able to give me crystal clear beer at the end more than once.

Comment: Concur with this.  Haven't used extract in a while, but I seem to remember it was usually hazy without some cold aging. I wasn't very familiar with clarifying agents back then, but they might help next time. In the mean time, maybe a couple of weeks in a cold fridge could help this batch. But the haze is aesthetic more than a threat to flavor.

Comment: @Bolwerk I can't see OP claiming to brew from extract? What am I missing? But honestly, it was all the same for me (answer updated).

Comment: Oh, maybe, I was just going by his use of cups instead of weight.  I don't usually see grain measured by the cup very often, but do see it with extract. Perhaps I was mistaken. (If I was, just ignore the part about extract.)